# How to start an external program with a file from a C program when both paths have spaces?

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I'm trying to fix an existing C-program with VS2005 that eventually calls

```
int system(command) //in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\crt\src\system.c)
```

with parameter value

```
start C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe C:\Documents and Settings\me\My Documents\My Music\09 - Track09.mp3
```

the program to be started and the filename paths are both formed from env variables that are got and the command start is appended to start of char buffer. The env variables are:

- `%VLCPATH%` which has value `C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC`
- `%MUSIC%` which has value `C:\Documents and Settings\me\My Documents\My Music`

I've been trying this with XP Command Prompt and everything works fine when paths don't have spaces. Also this works:

```
"%VLCPATH%\vlc.exe" "%MUSIC%\09 - Track09.mp3"
```

So what should I do?

1. edit env variables to have quotes? (Don't think so)
2. check if command has file as parameter and then somehow add quotes with escape character to maybe both of them and remove the word start?
3. do something sensible / elegant that I'm not aware of

Comment: Can you use `execv()` instead of `system()`?  The tricky part on Windows is the `fork()` equivalent.  But avoiding the 'shell' (`cmd.exe`) is probably the best way to go.

Comment: As a general rule you should always quote commands.  Quote the executable itself and any parameters that are paths.

Comment: @jonathan: i'm sorry but i didn't understand completely. I have to find out about this execv...

@Luke: so I should remove the start and manipulate the "string" with some escape characters so that it contains quotes?

Comment: Check out [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx).  You may still need quotes.

Comment: and thanks for both for fast reply!!

Comment: the thing is that this code is used from so many places that I can't make any big changes. otherwise the testing effort is much bigger than the gain for fixing the problem that nobody has complained...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try quoting all of the parameters, for example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char command[1024];
  char *title = "test vlc";
  char *executable = "vlc.exe";
  char *param = "09 - Track09.mp3";

  snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "start \"%s\" \"%s\" \"%s\"",
           title, executable, param);
  printf("%s\n", command);
  system(command);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Obviously replace executable and param with however you determine your executable and params.

Comment: this doesn't work on XP Command Prompt: it starts 09 - Track09.mp3 with default program which is Media Player. It ignores the first parameter for start (vlc program).

Comment: sorry, but I have to make few changes to try this code. but the Command Prompt does not accept the
<pre>
start "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "C:\Documents and Settings\me\My Documents\My Music\09 - Track09.mp3"
</pre>

Comment: @matti, The first parameter to the "start" command is a window title, not the executable.  I have updated my solution, please try it and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, both the program path to start and any arguments with pathnames need to be enclosed in double quotation marks ("like this") if they contain spaces.

For example:

"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "C:\Documents and Settings\me\My Documents\My Music\09 - Track09.mp3"

Comment: thanks. but what about the start? can this be done with start in the beginning of the "string" ??

Comment: this doesn't work on XP Command Prompt: it starts 09 - Track09.mp3 with default program which is Media Player. It ignores the first parameter for start (vlc program).

Comment: Sorry, removed "start".
The second part in quotes (the file argument) will now be passed on to vlc.exe as a single command line argument.

Comment: thanks for your effort but as I state in my question I know this works. I tried it before asking...